# How to complete the dssc checkout.?

Tags: version-control, dssc

I am running a command and it asks me to enter comment. It hangs when i enter a comment. Can someone help you how to proceed?

dssc co -lock

### Enter a check-out log message to describe your modifications.
Terminate the comment with a single '.' on a line by itself, or 'quit' to abort.

: testing
:

How to i proceed to checkout

Comment: Are you using  the single `.` in a line by itself?